# OpenJDK Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, openjdk

I'm trying to install openjdk on Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 2.

After the upgrade from beta 1 to beta 2, openjdk 8 was installed and openjdk 7 was removed. When trying to install openjdk 7 I get the following message:

```
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
```

is only available from another source

Oracle JDK is not an option for me and I have no problem install that. I need OpenJDK.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

- Rebuilding the sources.list from a link I found here in one of the posts.
- Downloading and completely reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04.

None of the above helped.

Comment: Off-topic?  Thank goodness this was raised here and the solution provided below.

Comment: Maybe not off-topic, but certainly a duplicate. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem, solved using this unofficial repo
https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ubuntu/openjdk-fontfix

before you need to install this version of tzdata

http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2016c-0%2bdeb7u1_all.deb

Comment: the repo works but after trying apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk i get              Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jdk : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (= 7u95-2.6.4-1ppa1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: solved using both this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/all/tzdata/download and this https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/tzdata-java/download. i do thank you though pal.