# Since ubuntu 16.04 javaws no longer run app while previously run fine on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, 16.04

Since ubuntu 16.04, I can't launch java web start app.
On ubuntu 15.10 it was Okay

```
crash@Dell-Latitude-E6520:~$ javaws Téléchargements/asdm.jnlp
  Codebase matches codebase manifest attribute, and application is signed. 
Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details. 
netx: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. ( ( (For input string: "03-Ubuntu"))) 
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Launch Error: Could not launch JNLP file. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws/browser from the command line and send a bug report.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:580)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:936)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:574)
    ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "03-Ubuntu"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.cisco.launcher.ClassUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: The problem is that the Cisco code is not robust enough, so it fails when parsing something it expects to be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me after I used sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

Then I installed openjdk as seen in the link [How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/ubuntu-16-04-and-openjdk-7)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be Ubuntu bug #1550244: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1550244.

A fix does not seem to be available for Ubuntu 16.04 just yet but I grabbed the openjdk packages from Ubuntu 16.10, installed them on 16.04, and that fixed the problem.

Cheers,

Eloy Paris.-