# Oracle-Java8-Installer: No installation candidate

Tags: apt, java, oracle

I'm trying to install Oracle Java 8 on my Ubuntu Server (16.04 LTS, fully updated, x64), following [this (very simple) guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html).

After running `apt-get update`, I get the standard list of sites having been hit for the update, but I get the following error (which I imagine is the source of the issue):

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
404 not found
```

All of the other URLs work, just not the `amd64` endpoint.

Then, when running `apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`, I get the following error:

```
 Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
 E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

Is that endpoint just not available anymore? Is there another source for Oracle Java 8? I see the `webupd8` group mentioned on pretty much every guide, besides using `dpkg` to install the package manually (but then do I get updates from Oracle?)

Comment: Attention!!! - **THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED** - http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

Comment: No answer worked for me(ubuntu 18.04). https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/  this link worked for me.

Comment: According to reason was mention by @RafafTahsin comment, now you can install Java using one of two solution https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/214624 or https://askubuntu.com/a/56119/214624

Comment: sudo apt install default-jre

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> NOTE: This answer no longer works, as the WebUpd8 PPA has been deprecated since Oracle has changed licensing and access restrictions to the Oracle Java codebase.  Details at http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html

The mistake is that you used instructions on how to install java on Debian.  Not Ubuntu.

1. As root, go to this folder: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
2. Locate this file: `webupd8team-java.list` and delete it.
3. Execute `sudo apt-get update` for the system to remove any reference to that update server.
4. Execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` to add the correct ppa to your system.
5. Execute `sudo apt-get update` again and you should be able to install everything correctly.

I would recommend you installed `oracle-java8-set-default` too, in order to make this java package the default java on your system.

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/ this link worked for me.

Comment: can be installed with:

`sudo apt install default-jre`
OR
`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless`
OR
`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless`

Comment: Alternatively, you can also install Java 7/8 as explained in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161572/830570

Comment: What @itsazzad  said worked for me in Aug 2021

Answer (score 9):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.
> Installing via ppa repository is no supported by Ubuntu 20.04

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Then , to install a specific jdk run these:

jdk6:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

jdk7:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

jdk8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Another way of doing it is by installing through synaptic. An upvote for me @ycomp

Comment: this no longer works - there's now 404s for the binaries

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/ this link worked for me.

Comment: It looks like all of these packages have been removed from the webupd8team PPA.

Comment: Instructions to install Open JDK on Ubuntu here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/03/install-oracle-java-12-ubuntu-18-04-16-04/

Comment: Alternatively, you can also install Java 7/8 as explained in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161572/830570

Answer (score 3):

### tl;dr:

You might want an older Java than 11<sup>[(tutorial for that)](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/)</sup>. If you do, [click through here to install Oracle Java 8](https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp).  Note that the license has changed.

---

### Reason(s) to need that

My recent Ubuntu (as of July 28th, 2019)

> uses the Java version 11 which is currently not supported by JabRef
> ([Source](http://help.jabref.org/en/Installation#installation-commands))

and I needed to use **JabRef** - this might apply to other software as well.

Therefore I issued `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

as found in [the op's link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html) and [other answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/854553/830570), [including the still accepted one](https://askubuntu.com/a/790674/830570), which for me led to:

> *[long explanation you get see below]*

> For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation).

### Solution

The workaround that went well for my case was to

> install a supported version of Java (7 or 8) via Oracle's website

(See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) → Introduction/2. Oracle Java - thanks to [pang](https://askubuntu.com/users/837532/pang) for fixing the broken link)

To do so, click through to [this site](https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp), download the respective fitting file and follow the given Instructions.

I unfortunately found no other way than calling it with the absolute path, but this works. In my case for example

```bash
cd /usr/java/jre1.8.0_221/bin/
./java -jar ~/bin/JabRef.dir/JabRef-4.3.1.jar #or where your .jar file lies
```

If Java 11 is not a problem for you, you probably want to use [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/).
(Thanks to [Saleh Enam Shohag](https://askubuntu.com/users/305799/saleh-enam-shohag) for [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790671/oracle-java8-installer-no-installation-candidate/1161572#comment1898424_854553))

---

> [**[long explanation]**](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)
>
> The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16,
> 2019.
>
> The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE
> is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new
> license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development
> use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK
> licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully
> before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here:
> https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html
>
> Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to
> download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE
> 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java
> (and the old links were broken by Oracle).
>
> For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way
> around this limitation).
>
> Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs
> Oracle JDK8). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.
>
> Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work:
> http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html
>
> Update: Oracle Java 9 has reached end of life:
> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html
>
> The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.10, 18.04, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04.
>
> More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
>
> - http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html
>
> Debian installation instructions:
>
> - Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html
>
> For Oracle Java 11, see a different PPA ->
> https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html
> More info: [https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)