# How do I choose a Java installation package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, openjdk

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jre-headless is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b130+9b130arm-1~webupd8~0
  oracle-java8-installer 8u101+8u101arm-1~webupd8~2
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jre-headless' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not sure how to "explicitly select one to install". How do I do that?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471564/installing-openjdk-7-jre-on-ubuntu-10-04-package-openjdk-7-jre-has-no-installa is giving you the right direction to resolve your problem

Comment: Which command did you issue? Also, since you are trying to install Oracle Java from webupd8 ppa, the command you need to issue is: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` for Java version 7 or `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` for Java version 8 or `sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer` for Java version 9.

Comment: " sudo apt-get install git openjdk-7-jre-headless tar  "    https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/#linux  i'm 99% sure java is already installed. what i'm trying to get is build tools from spiggot

Comment: Do what the message says: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` Replace java8 with 7 or 9 as you want.

Answer (score 8):

`You should explicitly select one to install.` means you need to issue command to install 1 of the 3 suggested packages, which provide similar functionality of `openjdk-7-jre-headless` which is currently unavailable. You can issue command like these

`sudo apt install oracle-java9-installer` or
`sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer` or
`sudo apt install oracle-java7-installer`

---

**As a note**, you should know that, there is no component of OpenJDK-7 in xenial release and therefore `openjdk-7-jre-headless` package is non-existent. See here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-7-jre. OpenJDK-7 has been dropped in the latest LTS and you need to install openjdk-8 or openjdk-9 to use openjdk (in contrast to Oracle JDK)

I suggest using openjdk-8 instead and replace all the packages containing name `openjdk-7` with `openjdk-8` and proceed with installation. This will resolve the issue for Xenial.

If you really want to stay with OpenJDK 7, Look at this question

- [How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/761127/61218)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I installed one and I still got the same prompt.

Comment: @TimothySwan this depends on the packager and packages being available on ubuntu. Try to use java8 or 9 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from:

[Can't install Oracle Java 8 in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966107/cant-install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-16-04)

This problem occured again, because version 151 has been archived. This version is referenced currently by the PPA. You can use the following commands to update the reference to 161:

```bsh
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="6dbc56a0e3310b69e91bb64db63a485bd7b6a8083f08e48047276380a0e2021e"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_161|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```