# Can't install Oracle Java 8 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, oracle

I haven’t installed anything strange in my Ubuntu 16.04 Server. I did some tests in my Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop VM some hours before and installation was successful, but in my dedicated it seems something is wrong.

Explanation:

1. I reinstalled the OS on my dedicated from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu Server 16.04)
2. Just open SSH first time, I go for

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Then I tried to install Oracle Java 8

   ```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle JDK7 /

   Important -> Why Oracle Java 7 And 6 Installers No Longer Work: http://www.webup

   Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak is no longer supported by Canonical (and thus, Launchpad)

   More info (and Ubuntu installation instructions):
   - for Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in
   - for Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubu

   Debian installation instructions:
   - Oracle Java 7: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-
   - Oracle Java 8: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-

   Oracle Java 9 (for both Ubuntu and Debian): http://www.webupd8.org/2015/02/insta

   Oracle JDK 9 is now considered stable. There are currently only 64bit builds (nodownloads/index.html )
    More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
   Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

   gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp64tvseig/secring.gpg' created
   gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp64tvseig/pubring.gpg' created
   gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
   gpg: /tmp/tmp64tvseig/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
   gpg: key EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
   ```

   then

   ```
   $ sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
   sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-
   Hit:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial InRelease
   Hit:2 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-backports InRelease
   Hit:3 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates InRelease
   Hit:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/security xenial-security InRelease
   Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease [17.5 kB
   Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
   Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
   Hit:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
   Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
   Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packag
   Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Package
   Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-
   Fetched 126 kB in 0s (175 kB/s)
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   The following additional packages will be installed:
     binutils gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libfontenc1 libxfont1 oracle-java8-se
   Suggested packages:
     binutils-doc binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-c
     ttf-arphic-uming firefox | firefox-2 | iceweasel | mozilla-firefox | iceape-br
     | midbrowser | moblin-web-browser | xulrunner | xulrunner-1.9 | konqueror | ch
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     binutils gsfonts gsfonts-x11 java-common libfontenc1 libxfont1 oracle-java8-in
   0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
   Need to get 6,519 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 20.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
   Get:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 binutil
   Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 oracle-
   Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 oracle-
   Get:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/main amd64 java-common all
   Get:5 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/main amd64 gsfonts all 1:8
   Get:6 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/main amd64 libfontenc1 amd
   Get:7 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 libxfon
   Get:8 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/main amd64 x11-common all
   Get:9 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/main amd64 xfonts-encoding
   Get:10 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial-updates/main amd64 xfonts
   Get:11 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages xenial/universe amd64 gsfonts-x1
   Fetched 6,519 kB in 0s (24.8 MB/s)
   Preconfiguring packages ...
   Selecting previously unselected package binutils.
   (Reading database ... 57317 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../binutils_2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.5_amd64.deb ...
   Unpacking binutils (2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.5) ...
   Selecting previously unselected package java-common.
   Preparing to unpack .../java-common_0.56ubuntu2_all.deb ...
   Unpacking java-common (0.56ubuntu2) ...
   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
   Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
   Setting up binutils (2.26.1-1ubuntu1~16.04.5) ...
   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
   Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
   (Reading database ... 57533 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u144-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
   Unpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
   Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
   Setting up java-common (0.56ubuntu2) ...
   Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u144-1~webupd8~0) ...
   No /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
   Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
   using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
   Downloading Oracle Java 8...
   --2017-10-18 19:34:47--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
   Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 2.20.189.226, 2.20.190.214
   Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.20.189.226|:80... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
   Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
   --2017-10-18 19:34:47--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
   Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2a02:26f0:78:18e::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:78:196::2d3e, 104.108.49.101
   Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2a02:26f0:78:18e::2d3e|:443... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
   Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508348207_951d79ba516ffabdf4dcbded7e76c54f [following]
   --2017-10-18 19:34:47--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1508348207_951d79ba516ffabdf4dcbded7e76c54f
   Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|2.20.189.226|:80... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
   2017-10-18 19:34:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.

   download failed
   **Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
   dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    oracle-java8-installer
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
   ```

   These output says at the end:

   ```
   **Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
   dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    oracle-java8-installer
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
   ```

Maybe I should try to install Oracle JDK 8?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this thread on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686) it seems to be a problem on WebUpd8's side.

Until they fix it, install it manually:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html

Comment: where is the download link? there just instructions.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: for ubuntu x64 server is rpm or witouth rpm?

Comment: RPM stands for  "Red Hat Package Manager". Use it if your distribution is Red Hat. Otherwise, go for DEB

Comment: download link is broken.  Unable to find archived files of old versions on oracle site ( I think they want to coerce people toward new versions )

Comment: As of today, [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&page=4&p=13731177#post13731177) (enhancing @PedroGalvao answer) gives the comands you should run to get Java 8 installed, after getting those errors.

Comment: You can monkey patch the `dkpg` info file to make it use a version that Oracle hasn't archived using this info (below): https://askubuntu.com/a/996986/754455

Answer (score 33):

This problem occurred again because version 161 has been archived. This version is referenced currently by the PPA. You can use the following commands to update the reference to 172 (171+bug fixes, refer Oracle's Java Downloads<sup>1</sup>):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info

sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|JAVA_VERSION=8u172|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u172-b11/a58eab1ec242421181065cdc37240b08/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="6dbc56a0e3310b69e91bb64db63a485bd7b6a8083f08e48047276380a0e2021e"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="28a00b9400b6913563553e09e8024c286b506d8523334c93ddec6c9ec7e9d346"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_161|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_172|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

<sup>1</sup> Java SE 8u172 is a patch-set update, including all of 8u171 plus additional bug fixes (described in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)).

Comment: I'm wondering if the building of a new apt-package could be automated, based on the current targeted version being archived on the Oracle Java downloads site.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the problem is that the PPA is trying to download java8U144 which is now an archived version so the URL is different (accessible via `http://download.oracle.com/otn/` not `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/`)

The only versions that aren't archived and accessible via otn-pub are 151 and 152.

You can use this temporary workaround, until they fix this on their side.

switch to dpkg directory

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

Then run the following commands :-

```
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u144|JAVA_VERSION=8u152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="e8a341ce566f32c3d06f6d0f0eeea9a0f434f538d22af949ae58bc86f2eeaae4"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="218b3b340c3f6d05d940b817d0270dfe0cfd657a636bad074dcabe0c111961bf"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_144|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: This installs 152, you can also use 161 which is in @gerwin-koudijs 's answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/996986/754455