# How can I install the icedtea 7 plugin on 16.04?

Tags: java, openjdk, icedtea

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04, and need to run a Java 7 applet in Firefox, so I installed  OpenJDK 7 following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04).  Now when I test my java version this is what I get:

```
% java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

Now I need the Iced Tea plugin so I can run Java 7 applets in Firefox, but icedtea-7-plugin is no longer available.

```
% sudo apt install icedtea-7-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package icedtea-7-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'icedtea-7-plugin' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone tell me where to find the correct plugin and how to install it?