# Error installing openjdk-7

Tags: java, openjdk, 16.10

I tried installing `opendjk-7` in the way that was suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04),
but I get this error:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It means there is no package for Ubuntu 16.10. You can ask the maintainer to make one for 16.10 or find other PPAs that do so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpenJDK is available from the default repos.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pagckage for Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety). Check [openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/](http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) .
Try to install `openjdk9` instead

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk
```