# How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: java, 16.10, openjdk

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/761527/98504) for Ubuntu 16.10, but after running this

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

This error happened

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
 N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is   therefore potentially dangerous to use.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And after trying to install it

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

This error occurred

```
E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install openjdk-7 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: Why not openjdk-8? `openjdk-7` is obsolete.

Comment: I want to build android-6.0.1 and it requires "1.7.x"

Comment: The easiest way is to install a virtual machine for that.

Answer (score 3):

I followed I am Dev's answer with the addition of downloading other dependencies manually. In total I had to download following packages off the [Debian page](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/java/):

```
libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u121-2.6.8-2_amd64.deb
openjdk-7-jre_7u121-2.6.8-2_amd64.deb
openjdk-7-jdk_7u121-2.6.8-2_amd64.deb
```

And install them with

```
sudo dpkg -i <deb file>
```

Whenever the installation complains about missing dependencies, you can run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to resolve them unless the dependency is one of the downloaded packages. In that case, you just have to install those first with dpkg.

Should you already have a Java version installed, you can select the OpenJDK binaries using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: Nowadays (2022) I've found openjdk-7-jdk at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/

Answer (score 1):

Download .deb file from below link https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/openjdk-7-jdk/download by selecting mirror. 
then type ccommand
**sudo dpkg -i openjdk-7-jdk_7u121-2.6.8-2_amd64.deb**

Comment: This command is not installing dependencies. The error is: "Package openjdk-7-jre is not installed." Then I tried to install openjdk-7-jre and similar error appeared: "Package openjdk-7-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package libjpeg62-turbo is not installed.  Package libatk-wrapper-java-jni is not installed." Should I continue to download every dependencies manually?

Comment: If it shows dependency problem use command: sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: It brings me back before running dpkg command!! It says: "... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: ... The following packages will be REMOVED:  openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre ..."

Comment: first clean the cache. try 'sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean' then 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade' after that install above .deb file. If it shows dependency problem then run 'sudo apt-get install -f'

Comment: It didn't work. The same as before!