# openjdk-7-jdk (package)

Tags: 16.04

I am searching for a package of openjdk but i can't find it, every time gives me this response " sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jdk' has no installation candidate"
how to solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you just need OpenJDK in general and not specifically version 7, run:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

for the whole JDK or:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

for just the runtime for running applications that use Java (e.g. Minecraft).  If you need version 7 specifically, see [How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher).