# OpenJDK 7 jre required

Tags: openjdk, gdebi

I have .deb package when I try to install it with **Gdebi** it return:
`Error dependency is not satisfiable openjdk-7 jre`

I have `openjdk-8 jre` installed but it still appeared

referring to [How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher) I have tried this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa  
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

but  it can't install `openjdk-7 jre`

I have Ubuntu 17.04

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can still install this using the deb file. It just takes a second command.

1. Open Terminal
2. Type:

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`

For example:

```
sudo dpkg -i /Downloads/openjdk-7-jdk_7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb
```

3. Then type:

`sudo apt-get install -f`

This will install any dependencies you need.

Openjdk 7 should now be installed. In order to have your system use Openjdk 7 as default, you will need to run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: after downloading deb file and running `sudo dpkg -i` retutns an error maybe because one of the dependencies is unavailable thanks

Comment: It will return an error. You then need to run the command in  step 3 of my post. That will take care of any dependencies that are needed.

Comment: that doesn't help