# Removing a particular version of libfontconfig1

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I mistakenly dpkg-ed libfontconfig1 on Ubuntu 16.04 by running following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libfontconfig1_2.12.3-0.2_amd64.deb
```

And now it conflicts with previously installed libfontconfig1. Following the list:

```
$sudo dpkg --list libfontconfig1
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

||/ Name                 Version            Architecture Description
+++-====================-==================-============-============================================
rU  libfontconfig1:amd64 2.12.3-0.2         amd64        generic font configuration library - runtime
iF  libfontconfig1:i386  2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 i386         generic font configuration library - runtime
```

And I'm not able to remove it because seems it's a major package and is a dependency for many other packages: all of them require a version (which is lower than 2.12.3-0.2) **or greater** version. And seems because of **or greater** condition, the version 2.12.3-0.2 is being blocked for removal, even though I have other version installed. When I run

```
sudo apt-get purge  libfontconfig1:amd64
```

It doesn't allow me, because many things depends on lower or equal version of the package:

```
firefox : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94) but it is not going to be installed
libbluray1 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
libcairo2 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
...
```

Removing through dpkg also not helpful:

```
$sudo dpkg --remove libfontconfig1:amd64
libqtwebkit4:amd64 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0).
openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 depends on libfontconfig1.
libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0).
fontconfig depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94).
...
dpkg: error processing package libfontconfig1:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libfontconfig1:amd64
```

When I run *sudo apt-get -f install* I get following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libfontconfig1: Depends: fontconfig-config (>= 2.12.3-0.2) but 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
                Breaks: libfontconfig1:i386 (!= 2.12.3-0.2) but 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
libfontconfig1:i386 : Breaks: libfontconfig1 (!= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) but 2.12.3-0.2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

So, how do I remove a particular version of libfontconfig1 package?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `dpkg` has an `--ignore-depends` option. Have you tried that?

Comment: @muru thanks for the response! this option requires to list all the deps which is more than 80.. I'm trying to find a way to ignore all, but so far no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing a libfontconfig1:amd64 section in 
`/var/lib/dpkg/status`.
Then I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` (had to remove `/usr/share/doc/libfontconfig1/` directory). The idea is described 
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/739274/ignore-all-dependencies-for-a-specific-package-with-apt-get?newreg=de6effb3169e40b49febe6f64d3c0d4d).

Also, the original goal was to install openjdk-7-jdk (this is why I had to dpkg libfontconfig1), [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/803616/487034) was helpful.