# How can I install open JDK 7 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: software-installation, openjdk

I need openjdk to build my Android ROM, but I can't install it. I installed Oracle JDK but it doesn't work.

Comment: is it still suported ? from what have you tried to install it ?

Comment: from standart repositories and ppa

Comment: [This might help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher/761527#761527).

Comment: @karel I don't think it's a duplicate. In the suggested duplicate Java version installed is Oracle's. OpenJDK 7 was in 14.04 which is now EOL. But here OP wants to install OpenJDK on 18.04.

Comment: @Vijay For some reason openjdk-r haven't ported JDK 7 for 18.04. **вася пупкин**: IMO you can't install OpenJDK7 on 18.04 due to dependency issues.

Comment: @Kulfy The last time openjdk-7-jdk was available from the default Ubuntu repositories was in 14.04. I'm not an advocate of trying to install openjdk-7-jdk from 14.04 in 18.04 because the problem of resolving package dependencies may be unsurmountable whereas Oracle JDK 7 installs clean as one bundle with no external Java dependencies.

Comment: @karel Yeah I agree but IMO that post doesn't answers this question so can't be considered as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Just for the record book Google is adamant about insisting on JDK 8 for Android development these days, not JDK 7 or 11. openjdk-8-jdk is in the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories.

Answer (score -1):

First install OpenJDK7:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo wget -P ~/Downloads http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jdk_7u161-2.6.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget -P ~/Downloads http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre_7u161-2.6.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget -P ~/Downloads http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u161-2.6.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo wget -P ~/Downloads http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.2-2+b1_amd64.deb
sudo update-alternatives --config java

cd ~/Downloads

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt install -f
#choose Java7
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now install Maven:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Install Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 SR2

```bsh
sudo su
cd /opt
sudo wget -P ~/Downloads http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
tar -xvf eclipse*.tar.gz
```

Now edit the `eclipse.ini` file:

```bsh
sudo nano /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini  <br/>
```

and change:

## If you run in Performance Issues, find for your self the best XMS/XMX Range

## Texteditor start

```bsh
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417

-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m

--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m

#Texteditor end
```

Now run eclipse:

```bsh
cd /usr/local/bin 
echo 'ECLIPSE=/opt/eclipse/eclipse' >eclipse 
echo 'exec $ECLIPSE "$@"' >>eclipse 
chmod +x eclipse
exit
eclipse
```

Add eclipse to the Desktop:

```bsh
sudo nano /opt/eclipse/eclipse.desktop
```

and add:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Save and exit and execute:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse.desktop
sudo cp /opt/eclipse/eclipse.desktop ~/Schreibtisch
sudo mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
sudo cp /opt/eclipse/eclipse.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Wilffly 8.2.1
sudo su
sudo wget -P /opt https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/8.2.1.Final/wildfly-8.2.1.Final.tar.gz
cd /opt
tar -xvzf wildfly*.tar.gz
sudo mv wildfly-8.2.1.Final wildfly
Add Management-User
sudo /opt/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh

sudo nano /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/mgmt-users.properties

Wildfly Verknüpfungen erstellen
sudo  wget -P /opt/wildfly/bin https://api.jujucharms.com/v5/precise/wildfly-5/icon.svg
sudo nano /opt/wildfly/bin/wildflyapplicationserver.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Wildfly Standalone 8.2.1
Comment=Wildfly Application Server authored by JBoss
Icon=/opt/wildfly/bin/icon.svg
Exec=/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh
Terminal=true
Categories=Development
StartupWMClass=Wildfly

sudo chmod +x /opt/wildfly/bin/wildflyapplicationserver.desktop
sudo cp /opt/wildfly/bin/wildflyapplicationserver.desktop ~/Schreibtisch
sudo cp /opt/wildfly/bin/wildflyapplicationserver.desktop ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1143428/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)** Also please leave a link at the bottom of your answer for any source material you've used unless you are **m.zenkert**

Comment: I took the freedom to simplify the eclipse installation steps a bit.

Comment: As OP asks to install OpenJDK 7, why should they also install Maven and Eclipse, change configuration files and add a `.desktop` file? In which way are these parts of your answer relevant to the question?

Comment: The PPA you suggest for installing OpenJDK 7 is out of date and missing important security patches (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761127/how-do-i-install-openjdk-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-or-higher/761527#comment1397153_761527)) – I think a warning would be appropriate.

Comment: What is the point of adding the PPA when you are trying to install JDK using deb packages? Also, this PPA haven't ported JDK7 for some reasons regarding which I've already left [comment on the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135787/how-can-i-install-open-jdk-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/1143428#comment1883372_1135787). Have you tried this on 18.04? Were you able top solve all dependency issues?

Comment: i know all this things.... ...missing security level and patches, but there are many developers out there, who still need to use java 7

Comment: and btw thx for editing ;)

Comment: And thx for editing :) your welcome  for that :)
The reason for the instructions for the installation of Maven and Eclipse, I just assume that it is needed ... just as a SVN or GIT or JBOSS Wildfly in compatible versions to Java7. So I will just offer the complete solution. :)

The real reason for the complete solution is that right now I need exactly that for our company and have the solution at hand, otherwise a complete rebuild will be necessary.

Comment: ~/Schreibtisch is the german designation of ~/desktop

Comment: I hope I could help. Unfortunately I do not have time anymore

Comment: thx to dessert for editing

Comment: Please review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers...  *It's a mess again.*  **-1**

Comment: It seems you are adding irrelevant details to the answer. Do you really think this question need Wilffly, Eclipse, etc?