# Install AdoptOpenJDK / Adoptium onto Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, java

I downloaded [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) 11 in the form of [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net). From the tar.gz file I can extract a folder named `jdk-11.0.3+7` with nested folders for `bin`, `conf`, `lib`, and so on. But no installer app found there.

➥ How should I install this downloaded Java release onto Ubuntu?

I can `cd` into the `bin` folder and execute commands like `./java --version`. But I wonder if there is a usual routine for placing the Java implementation somewhere specific, and arranging environment variables, setting default path, etc. On macOS, an installer does all that for me automatically. As I newbie on Ubuntu, I'm uneducated.

Older Questions such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/761127) ask about using `apt-get`. My Question is not a duplicate, as here I am asking about downloads from AdoptOpenJDK rather than via package-installer such as `apt-get`.

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) [is now superseeded by](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/03/transition-to-eclipse-an-update/) [*Adoptium*](https://adoptium.net/)

[How to properly install Temurin JDK with update-alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1375383/how-to-properly-install-temurin-jdk-with-update-alternatives/1386901#1386901)

[Adoptium provides a Debian / Ubuntu repository](https://blog.adoptium.net/2021/12/eclipse-temurin-linux-installers-available/)

```
wget -O - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install temurin-8-jdk
sudo apt install temurin-17-jdk
```

[*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) [provides a Debian / Ubuntu repository](https://medium.com/adoptopenjdk/adoptopenjdk-rpm-and-deb-files-7003ba38144e).

You can install using the package management system, which is much simpler than installing it manually.:

```
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot  # Java 8 / HotSpot VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-8-openj9   # Java 8 / OpenJ9 VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot # Java 11 / HotSpot VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-11-openj9  # Java 11 / OpenJ9 VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-12-hotspot # Java 12 / HotSpot VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-12-openj9  # Java 12 / OpenJ9 VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-13-hotspot # Java 13 / HotSpot VM
sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-13-openj9  # Java 13 / OpenJ9 VM
```

You can switch between e.g. OpenJDK, AdoptOpenJDK and Adoptium by using the following command.:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: note that (as of today) the repo has no entry for ubuntu impish & jammy. just use hirsute instead of your distro

Answer (score 2):

Since the use of apt-key was deprecated, you might see warnings like:

> Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8))

Hence, I'd recommend to use the following way:

### Option 1, use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/)

```bash
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
$ sdk install java 17.0.8-tem
```

### Option 2, install by apt

```bash
$ apt install ca-certificates curl gnupg
$ install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings

$ curl -fsSL https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.gpg
$ chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.gpg

$ echo "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.gpg] https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list

$ apt update -y
$ apt install temurin-17-jdk
```

### Verify the installation

Then verify your installed java by

```bash
$ java --version
```