# How to properly install Temurin JDK with update-alternatives

Tags: java, update-alternatives

I wanted to install Temurin JDK both 8 and 11, I installed them by these steps

```
wget https://github.com/adoptium/temurin8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u312-b07/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u312b07.tar.gz
tar xzf OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u312b07.tar.gz

sudo mv jdk8u312-b07/  /usr/lib/jvm/temurinjdk-8-hotspot-amd64

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/temurinjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin/java" 1081
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/temurinjdk-8-hotspot-amd64/bin/javac" 1081
```

But I am not sure if this is 100% right and how do I generate .jinfo file is that even needed?

Comment: I would recommend searching for documentation regarding the  Temurin JDK or visit their forums/sites.  Is there a read.me file or other installation instructions?

Comment: @TBr well there is and it just says do `export PATH=$PWD/jdk8u312-b07/bin:$PATH` and doesnt say anything about update-alternatives option which i like to use

Comment: The best answer I can give you is this then;  unless there is another user who has also installed this software and has chosen to use it as you have, only they would be able to provide a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [Adoptium Debian / Ubuntu repository](https://blog.adoptium.net/2021/12/eclipse-temurin-linux-installers-available/)

1. Add the Eclipse Adoptium GPG key

   ```
   wget -O - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the Eclipse Adoptium apt repository

   ```
   echo "deb https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list
   ```
3. Install the Temurin version you require

   ```
   sudo apt update # update if you haven't already
   sudo apt install temurin-8-jdk
   sudo apt install temurin-17-jdk
   ```
4. Configure the default version

   ```
   sudo update-alternatives --config java
   ```

Comment: E: The repository 'https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb una Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: The Adoptium procedure fails at nearly every steup on Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS (running in AWS). The error given in the comment above occurs, and also before that the warning 'Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
E: This command can only be used by root.' followed by 'W: GPG error: https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...'

Comment: This answer has minor flaws. The correct apt repository setup that worked in 03/2024 with Ubuntu 22.02 LTS is: https://askubuntu.com/a/1488200/18928

Answer (score 1):

I extracted script from original AdoptOpenJDK deb package and modified version I use like:

```
wget https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.1%2B12/OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.1_12.tar.gz

mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

sudo tar -xvvf OpenJDK17U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.1_12.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/

sudo ./java-alternative install /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12
sudo ./java-alternative set /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12
…
sudo ./java-alternative remove /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12
```

Source code of script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

priority=2222
#jdk_base_dir=/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-11-hotspot-amd64
#jdk_base_dir=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1+12
jdk_base_dir="$2"

if [ ! -d "$jdk_base_dir" ]
then
    echo "Invalid java directory. Choose one of: ";
    ls -1d /usr/lib/jvm/*
    exit
fi

tools="jaotc jar jarsigner java javac javadoc javap jcmd jconsole jdb jdeprscan jdeps jfr jhsdb jimage jinfo jjs jlink jmap jmod jps jrunscript jshell jstack jstat jstatd keytool pack200 rmic rmid rmiregistry serialver unpack200 jexec jspawnhelper"

case "$1" in
install)
    for tool in $tools ; do
        for tool_path in "$jdk_base_dir/bin/$tool" "$jdk_base_dir/lib/$tool" ; do
            if [ ! -e "$tool_path" ]; then
                continue
            fi

            slave=""
            tool_man_path="$jdk_base_dir/man/man1/$tool.1"
            if [ -e "$tool_man_path" ]; then
                slave="--slave /usr/share/man/man1/$tool.1 $tool.1 $tool_man_path"
            fi

            update-alternatives \
                --install \
                "/usr/bin/$tool" \
                "$tool" \
                "$tool_path" \
                "$priority" \
                $slave
        done
    done
;;
remove)
    for tool in $tools ; do
        for tool_path in "$jdk_base_dir/bin/$tool" "$jdk_base_dir/lib/$tool" ; do
            if [ ! -e "$tool_path" ]; then
                continue
            fi

            update-alternatives \
                --remove \
                "$tool" \
                "$tool_path"
        done
    done
;;
set)
    for tool in $tools ; do
        for tool_path in "$jdk_base_dir/bin/$tool" "$jdk_base_dir/lib/$tool" ; do
            if [ ! -e "$tool_path" ]; then
                continue
            fi

            update-alternatives \
                --set \
                "$tool" \
                "$tool_path"
        done
    done
;;
esac
```

Comment: Does this work with any SDK version like from 8 to 17?