# installing jdk 1.7

Tags: jdk

I have a need to remove jdk 1.8 and instead install jdk 1.7. Does Ubuntu 18.04 support RPM? Here are the choices I have, which one do I donwload and install?

Download File   Architecture    Who Can Install
jdk-7u-linux-x64.tar.gz    64-bit  anyone
jdk-7u-linux-i586.tar.gz   32-bit  anyone
jdk-7u-linux-x64.rpm   64-bit RPM-based Linux  root
jdk-7u-linux-i586.rpm  32-bit RPM-based Linux  root

Comment: RPM packages in ubuntu I would avoid always

Comment: Solved here: [How do I install openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 16.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/a/840945/502712)